# How to remove duplicates from a chapter-local list in ConTeXt?

Tags: lists, context

This code, found at [How to define items appearing in a list, which appears somewhere else in the document in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379929/how-to-define-items-appearing-in-a-list-which-appears-somewhere-else-in-the-doc), allows users to add items to a list by using the code `\definetopic{}`:

```
\definelist
  [topics]
  [criterium=chapter,
   headnumber=always,
   pagenumber=no]

\definecounter
  [topic]
  [way=bychapter]

\define[1]\definetopic{%
  \incrementcounter[topic]%
  \writetolist[topics]{\rawcountervalue[topic]}{#1}}

\starttext

\startchapter[title=Foo]
  This chapter will talk about:
  \placelist[topics]

  \startsection[title=Bar]
    \definetopic{How to build a temporary bridge from stones.}%
    \input knuth
    \definetopic{How to hunt for rabbits.}%
    \input knuth
    \definetopic{How to find firewood.}%
    \input knuth
  \stopsection
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=Foo]
  This chapter will talk about:
  \placelist[topics]

  \startsection[title=Bar]
    \definetopic{How to hunt for rabbits.}%
    \input knuth
  \stopsection
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Sometimes my source code calls for the same information to be added to a list, multiple times, e.g.:

```
\chapter{One}
   \definetopic{This is about rabbits.}

   \definetopic{This is about birds.}

   \definetopic{This is about rabbits.}
```

In such a case, I don't want the item to appear twice when calling `\placelist[topics]`. Is there any way to remove duplicate items from this list?

Comment: Sounds more like you want a `register` rather than a `list`.

Comment: Okay, I've tried changing to a register, but it adds page numbering to the left and other formatting? Is there a way to remove that so it is just plain text appearing in the document, e.g. to be put inside `\startitemize` and `\enditemize`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tried to change the `list` to a `register` and asked in the comments whether one can remove the additional formatting added by the `register`.  This is easily possible as I show in this example.  Furthermore, the `register` will be sorted alphabetically.

```
\defineregister
  [topics]
  [criterium=chapter,
   pagenumber=no,
   indicator=no,
   before=,
   n=1]

\def\definetopic{\topics}

\starttext

\startchapter[title=Foo]
  This chapter will talk about:
  \placeregister[topics]

  \startsection[title=Bar]
    \definetopic{How to build a temporary bridge from stones.}%
    \input knuth
    \definetopic{How to hunt for rabbits.}%
    \input knuth
    \definetopic{How to find firewood.}%
    \input knuth
  \stopsection
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=Foo]
  This chapter will talk about:
  \placeregister[topics]

  \startsection[title=Bar]
    \definetopic{How to hunt for rabbits.}%
    \input knuth
  \stopsection
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```